# Audited audited_changes confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-audited

Im using collectiveidea's audited solution for auditing in rails.
So, there's a column (audited_changes) that is a TEXT definition in the database. When i retrieve an audit from the database, i get a plain string, and when i call that attribute in the view is non formated string. In the [rdocs](http://rdoc.info/github/collectiveidea/audited/Audited/Adapters/ActiveRecord/Audit) it says that theres a serialized hash of all changes. How can i get this hash? Also, in the same docs it says that there's access to old_attributes and new_attributes, how is this?

In my view:

```
<%= @audit.action %> # => update
<%= @audit.audited_changes %> # => --- name: - oldname - newname code: - oldcode - newcode
```

Or any chance on formatting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there might currently be a bug in audited.  Are you using 3.0.0rc1?  That is what I am using and I had something similar happen.  First off, it didn't seem to recognize "Audit" as an ActiveRecord object, so I created an empty model in app/models/audit.rb.  Once I did that I was seeing the behaviour you are seeing.  To fix it, I removed the app/models/audit.rb and added an config/initializers/audited.rb with this in it:

```
include Audited::Adapters::ActiveRecord
```

Comment: Fantastic!, but i dont understand what happened, and why solved it this way?. Yes, im using 3.0.0rc1.

Comment: I filed a bug about it with audited: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/issues/101

It seems like some of the Audit modules aren't getting pulled in to ActiveRecord properly

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I have an alternative answer that seems to be working well for me using Rails 4.2. Instead of using the initializer in the above answer I suggest keeping the model and adding "serialize :audited_changes" to the top.

```
 class Audit < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   serialize :audited_changes
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in Audited::Audit model to query its data.

For example,

```
audit = Audited::Audit.last
audit.audited_changes # => {"name"=>["Steve", "Ryan"]}
```

"Steve" is the old value, "Ryan" is the new value. By default, the hash is stored in yaml format in the database.